# Select all check boxes at a time by clicking one UIButton

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, uibutton

Thanks all. But I need to tell you the full circumstances.I have a collection view cell.Inside that I have added checkboxes. and the 'select All ' button is outside of the collection view. So if I will click on 'select All' button the it should select all check boxes inside the collection view cell. I have added a customuibutton inside collection viewcell.                                         CustomUIButton *checkboxButton=[CustomUIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [checkboxButton setTaggy:indexPath.row];
        //[checkboxButton setTag:CHECKBOX_BUTON_ON_CELL+indexPath.row+indexPath.section];
       // [checkboxButton setCollectionIdentifier:collectionView.tag];
        [checkboxButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(checkBoxAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        checkboxButton.frame = CGRectMake(168.0, 3.0, 20.0, 20.0);
        [checkboxButton setSection:indexPath.section];

```
    [checkboxButton setHighlighted:NO];
    if (clsPartcipant.isSmallChanged)
    {
        [checkboxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [checkboxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [checkboxButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkboxButton];

    });

return cell;
```

the i called a function like checkBoxAction.                                               -(void)checkBoxAction:(id)sender{
    CustomUIButton *button=sender;
    BOOL flag = NO;

```
if (button.selected)
{
    [button setSelected:NO];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag=NO;

}
else
{
    [button setSelected:YES];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag=YES;
}

if (button.collectionIdentifier == ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView)
{
    [self ModifyDataArray:button.taggy flag:flag identifier:ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView change:@"SmallButton" toDate:nil section:button.section];
    [self modifyCollectionArray:PRESENT processingData:self.presentDataArray identifier:ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView index:button.taggy section:button.section];
}
```

}
Now I can't able to figure out what I need to add inside selectAll button action. Please help me in this

Comment: My answer is pretty much copy-paste for you. But make sure to read its comment. And mark as correct if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this from my phone so excuse the lack of code. Anyway i will be clear enough.

First you want to link your buttons as outlets, all of them, and give them a **tag**.

In storyboard or in code (in `viewDidLoad`), set a "checked" image for the `selected` state, and an "unchecked" image for the `not selected` state.

Now your buttons will know what to show when you interact with them.

For every button you probably already have an IBAction which is fine. Your SelectAll button needs his own too.

In all buttons you will have

```
UIButton *bt = (UIButton*)sender;
[bt setSelected:!bt.isSelected];
```

Now i Will have to check that as soon as i get to a computer but basically set the selected property of your button to the opposite of its current state.

For your select all, you can use this

```
BOOL trigger;
    UIButton *bt = (UIButton*)sender;
    If(bt.isSelected == YES){
         trigger = NO;
}else{
         trigger = YES
}

for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++){ // note that 9 is the number of buttons

UIButton *bt = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i]
[bt setSelected:trigger];
}
```

And you should be all set :)

Again please excuse any ridiculous mispel or french autocorrect im just on my phone and it took me 20 minutes to write that down :D

Comment: Though i'd like to mention that you should be able to come up with a solution by just doing research. In the end you could just hardcode all the buttons in your action just like the other answer suggests and it will work too. Im giving you a more optimal way (i believe) but this wont get you far if you dońt learn by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use `UITabelView` to show those check-boxes, that would be fine, reload it, or get All Cells then reload every cell.
Then if you have 10 check-boxes above `UIView`, you can use `NSMutableArray` to contain 10 check-boxes, like:

```
for(UIButton * button in mArray){
 // do select or deselect action
}
```